# Migrate frontend-maven-plugin from maven to gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin` in my `maven` project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.27</version>

    <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>bower install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>bower</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>

            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v4.2.4</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>2.7.1</npmVersion>
        <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
        <npmDownloadRoot>https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now I need to migrate it into `gradle` but I can't find examples how to do it. Grade migration tool translates only dependencies but not plugins. Is there some examples, how can I use `frontend-maven-plugin` in `gradle`?

Comment: Look at the [Gradle Plugin for Node](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin). The readme.md has a good explanation of how to install and configuring the plugin, how to executing npm tasks and node.js scripts.

Comment: I have made frontend build this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080747/configuring-nodemodulesdir-in-gradle-node-plugin

Comment: You should answer your own question instead of commenting it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may not find any example on how to use the `frontend-maven-plugin` in Gradle, as it is dedicated to Maven. But you may take a look at the [Siouan Frontend Gradle plugin](https://github.com/siouan/frontend-gradle-plugin), which is an equivalent solution for Gradle, and allows to (from official website):

> Integrate your frontend NPM/Yarn build into Gradle.

The usage and configuration seems close to your Maven configuration. Define the Node/NPM/Yarn version in your `build.gradle` file, link the scripts you want to be run depending on the Gradle lifecycle task (clean/assemble/check), and that's all. Below is a typical usage under Gradle 5.4 with NPM, taken from the docs:

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.siouan.frontend' version '1.1.0'
}

frontend {
    nodeVersion = '10.15.3'
    // See 'scripts' section in your 'package.json file'
    cleanScript = 'run clean'
    assembleScript = 'run assemble'
    checkScript = 'run check'
}
```

You'll notice:

- Contrary to the `frontend-maven-plugin`, there's no declaration/configuration to trigger the frontend build with Gradle, as it is already provided out of the box. The download, installation of Node/NPM/Yarn requires no declaration/configuration - except the version numbers, as well as the build tasks. Just provide the NPM/Yarn command line to clean/assemble/check your frontend.
- The mimimum supported version of Node shall be `6.2.1`. So your initial configuration with `4.2.4` will require to migrate Node.
- The plugin does not support Bower, and I don't think it will be supported in the future, as Bower now encourages migration to Yarn. You'll find a migration guide on Bower's website.
- The plugin does not support the use of a specific NPM release. NPM being now packaged with Node, the plugin uses the version embedded in the downloaded Node distribution.

Regards

Comment: There seem to be only like 4 stars as of this post on the repo.  Is it a stable repo? Anyone using it in production?

Comment: @Tamb, I'm a contributor of this plugin. The only answer I can give is to give it a try to have an opinion. On the project's homepage, you'll find information about supported platforms. Please use the issue tracker for any issue/feature request. BR

Comment: Using this plugin, can someone help me how to run npm tests during the test phase. Currently i am running using `checkScipt`. Is there alternate way during test phase of gradle life cycle. Apologies if my question is not clear enough and thank you for your help

Comment: @siddhuKantipudi, using the `test` task to execute npm tests is not recommended, because this task is not a built-in task in Gradle, and is dedicated to run Java unit tests. It is part of the Java plugin, which may be applied or not in a Gradle project. Like the Java plugin, the plugin provides its own task `checkFrontend` to run npm tests. If your goal is to run npm and Java unit tests together, then the `check` task shall be used. If you really want to run npm tests with the `test` task, you may add this line in your `build.gradle` file: `tasks.named('test').dependsOn('checkFrontend')`.

Comment: @vincent I think with this approach, test task will execute the npm tests twice during the test phase as well as in frontend build phase?

Comment: @siddhuKantipudi I don't think npm tests would be executed twice, if you execute the `check` task for example. Task dependencies can be seen as a way to reorganize task order, but does not add a task execution if a task is already present in the build.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for the clarification. In my case, I ended up writing custom task which runs during Junit test phase using the `RunNpmYarn` helper like you suggested.

Comment: Hey @Vincent. Can you please answer my question(I'm stuck for almost 5 days) I used the above mentioned way to include it.  On gradle clean build it showed me this error --
Execution failed for task ':installFrontend'

Answer (score 3):

Google found the [Gradle Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/subiron/gradle-frontend-plugin) for me.  The plugin description simply says:

> Set of tasks which wraps common frontend-tools and provide its binaries.

The documentation (as at March 2016) describes the 4 tasks (`installnode`, `npm`, `grunt` and `gulp`) and examples of their use.

---

An alternative (provided by @Timofei) is the [Gradle Plugin for Node](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin).  The description says:

> This plugin enables you to use NodeJS-based technologies as part of your build without having NodeJS installed locally on your system. It integrates Gradle with NodeJS, Yarn, Grunt, and Gulp.

(Edited for clarity)

Note that this plugin's Github repo is active while the previous one hasn't had any commits in the last two years.