# Configuring nodeModulesDir in gradle-node-plugin

Tags: node.js, gradle, gradle-plugin

I trying to set up caching of npm packages. This is my plugin configuration:

```
node {
  version = '4.5.0'
  npmVersion = '3.10.6'
  distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'
  download = true

  workDir = file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/nodejs")

  nodeModulesDir = file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/")
}
```

And this is my task:

```
task npmCacheConfig(type: NpmTask) {
  description = "Configure the NPM cache"
  outputs.upToDateWhen {
    false
  }
  def npmCacheDir = "${gradle.getGradleUserHomeDir()}/caches/npm"
  outputs.files file(npmCacheDir)
  args = ['config', 'set', 'cache', npmCacheDir]
}
```

But when I run this task, I got an error:

```
:arm-bpa:nodeSetup UP-TO-DATE
:arm-bpa:npmCacheConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myModule:npmCacheConfig'.
> 
  Could not run npm command - local npm not found but requested in gradle node configuration.
  A common reason for this is an npm-shrinkwrap.json file is present and un-installs npm.
  To resolve this, add npm with version '3.10.6' to your package.json.
```

I can fix it this way:

```
npmCacheConfig.doFirst {
  this.project.node.nodeModulesDir = file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/nodejs/node-v4.5.0-linux-x64/lib/")
}

npmCacheConfig.doLast {
  this.project.node.nodeModulesDir = file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/")
}
```

Is there any way to fix it without this hardcoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it this way:

```
npmCacheConfig.doFirst {
    def nodeJsDirectory = null
    def nodeVersion = this.project.node.version

    file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/nodejs/").traverse(
            type: FileType.DIRECTORIES,
            nameFilter: ~"^node-v$nodeVersion.*",
            postDir: {
                return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE
            }
    ) {
        nodeJsDirectory = it
    }

    if (nodeJsDirectory != null) {
        this.project.node.nodeModulesDir = file("$nodeJsDirectory/lib/")
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("nodejs is not installed")
    }
}


npmCacheConfig.doLast {
    this.project.node.nodeModulesDir = file("$webAppSourceAbsolute/")
}
```