# How to serve frontend using frontend maven plugin in gradle based project?

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-cli

I have read some online blogs that states adding this plugin builds Angular frontend so it would be easier to serve angular content from a spring boot path - `resources/static` folder. But couldn't find any example for gradle projects. 
I have a gradle project which consists of modules for backend and frontend and trying to host it on same server port. I added :

`compile group: 'com.github.eirslett', name: 'frontend-maven-plugin', version: '1.6'`

Then ran `ng build` in frontend dir to build ng components. I see some.js files and following index.html generated  :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

From my understanding adding above dependency just take care of install npm and node dependencies  but won't build ng components. So I manually ran ng build and the those files gets generated in resources/static directory(as I changed outputPath in angular.json). But unable to serve them from tomcat startup.

I just have 3 ng components where the main login component uri should be accessible at "/" and routing works fine and handled by angular(ng serve shows UI pages) but just not when in spring-boot path so as to deploy on same server port as backend.

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    // empty path is the default page for app; redirects to Login component
    path: '',
    component: LgnComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'sale',
    component: SaleComponent
  }
])
```

My only problem is http://localhost:8080/ displays no UI(login etc.)

> I mean to ask are there  any additional steps beyond adding this
>   dependency to build.gradle in order to easily serve them?

I guess I don't know what URI to use to access frontend on 8080. Because angular routing works fine and was able to access on localhost:4200/ and from the main login page to localhost:4200/test and /sale .

Please help, I have been struggling/banging my head on this issue for sometime now.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin seems a bit outdated.

I am using the [gradle node plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md). You add the build command to package.json and then execute the script via the plugin:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stuff",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "buildProd": "ng build -prod"
  }
...
}
```

build.gradle:

```
//execute buildProd script from project.json
task buildClient(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: [npmInstall]) {
    args = ['run-script', 'buildProd']
}

task copyClient(type: Copy, dependsOn: [buildClient]) {
    from 'dist'
    into "${buildDir}/resources/main/static"
}
 
//build & copy client before processResources
processResources.dependsOn copyClient
```

Comment: I don't have any project.json. Although I see scripts in package.json
 "build": "ng build". All I want is a way to serve angular content easily by spring-boot app so that it's easily deployable.

Comment: Secondly, I can have these tasks to build and copy rather than manually doing it. But after trying different options, the point is spring-boot doesn't seem to pick the index.html or any other static file from resources/static to display on 8080.

Comment: Sorry, I meant package.json. You should copy your angular app to the build/resources/main/static directory of your spring boot app to serve it.

Comment: Sorry for the late update but it worked. I put the static contents to serve themfrom src/main/resources.

Answer (score 1):

Building your frontend application in Gradle with the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) is not relevant, because this plugin is designed for Maven, not Gradle. You may take a look at the [Siouan Frontend Gradle plugin](https://github.com/Siouan/frontend-gradle-plugin), that will allow you to trigger your frontend application build directly from Gradle. From the official website:

> It is inspired by the frontend-maven-plugin.

This [other answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825555) provides an example of how to use this plugin. Here's a minimal configuration example to build your frontend application:

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.siouan.frontend' version '1.1.2'
}

frontend {
    // Replace with your Node version.
    nodeVersion = '10.15.3'
    // Replace 'build' by the name of your script in your project's 'package.json' file.
    assembleScript = 'run build'
}
```

Having your freshly built frontend application served by your Spring Boot backend and correctly packaged in your final archive are different problems. You'll find a working example of a Angular + Spring Boot + Gradle application by generating a demo application with [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) and its [JHipster Online](https://start.jhipster.tech/) service. This will also show you where the different artifacts are generated to be served either by the backend or the frontend development server.

**EDIT**

The plugin's homepage now provides some usage guidelines, that may help 'packaging' a frontend and a Java backend together.